# Using ViewBinder to update an image in a `ListView` row

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, android-viewbinder

I have a `ListView` populated from a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, each row containing some `TextViews` and an `ImageView`. I want to change the `ImageView` for each row depending on some values, however I'm trying to first figure out how to update the `ImageView` in the list after it's populated. I tried this code but the `ImageView` remains the same:

```
cursorAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {         
            int viewId = view.getId();         
            Log.v("ViewBinder", "columnIndex=" + columnIndex + " viewId = " + viewId);        
            if(viewId == R.id.imageloc)        
            {  
              sign2 = (ImageView) view;
              sign2.setImageResource(R.drawable.other);

              return true;          
          } 
          return false;      
          } 
        });
```

If anyone can help me I would appreciate it!

Comment: Are you also calling `setAdapter` on the ListView with your `cursorAdapter`?

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to update the ImageView depending on some values, if those values are stored on the DB, you could perform the SQL query like this:

```
SELECT _id, name, CASE WHEN checked = 1 THEN 'R.drawable.check' ELSE 'R.drawable.check' END as img FROM table;
```

Doing it in this way, you would not need to use the setViewBinder() method. Just do the query, get the cursor, assign it to the SimpleCursorAdapter and assign the adapter to the list view.

```
Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchData(sqlQuery);
(...)
String[] from = new String[]{"name", "img"};
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text_view, R.id.imgageloc};
SimpleCursorAdapter _adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.data_rows, c, from, to);
setListAdapter (_adapter);
```

> Note: you'll need the integer value of R.drawable.check/R.drawable.check : " ... THEN '" + R.drawable.check + "' ELSE ..."

Hope it helps and is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sign2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.other);
```

Worked for me in a very similar situation where I was trying to set an image based on an `if statement`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you try to set different resource to  ImageView. It's always R.drawable.other. Change image resource based on your cursor data.

Comment: Sorry let me clarify, the imageview has a resource of R.drawable.check defined in the xml, and I want to set it to a different image if a certain criteria is met. However, I cant even get the image to change in the first place. If I can figure that out, I can take care of the rest!

Comment: Oh. I guess your image view is not root view. Remove checking view ID and get ImageView this way: view.findViewById(R.id.imageloc)

Comment: It didnt work :( the thing is this code all works perfectly if the object is a TextView and I have it change the text....its just the moment it becomes an ImageView it doesn't want to change the image. ugh

Comment: Ok. Show me please how you create adapter.

Comment: here it iis getListView().invalidateViews().